# Eigenvalues of $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to express ${\rm tr}A^2$ in terms of ${\rm tr}^2A$. $A$ is a $2\times2$ symmetric matrix. The best way seems to be expressing both in terms of eigenvalues of $A$. So, ${\rm tr}A=a_1+a_2$ and $\det A=a_1\cdot a_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric, so is $A^2$. The eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $a_1^2$ and $a_2^2$ (this can be seen by diagonalizing $A$), hence:

$$\operatorname{tr}(A^2)= a^2_1 + a_2^2 = (a_1+a_2)^2 - 2a_1a_2.$$

Do you see how one can rewrite the RHS with the help of $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ and $\det A$?

Answer (score 6):

If your matrix is given by say
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix},
$$
a direct computation shows that $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=a^2+2bc+d^2$ and $\operatorname{tr}^2(A)=a^2+2ad+d^2$ and hence

$$\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=\operatorname{tr}^2(A)-2\det A.$$
EDIT: In particular, this identity holds also for non-symmetric matrices.